# Why do images disappear after they're loaded?

Tags: google-chrome, images

Please visit this link: http://makkomua.com/?page=buildings&lang=eng

In this site images are being loaded by Chrome (I se part of them) then when they are loaded completely, they disappear. But other browsers work properly, what is the problem, Chrome or site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on [chrome forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=1d825178248ab136&hl=en) there is a similar question and an interesting answer :

> for me, it had nothing to do with adblock.  i was having the same problem, but it was for dynamically generated images i was getting from a php script.  i found that by removing the "Content-Length" from the header i was pushing for the image (to chrome browsers v5-6, mac, windows, linux) it fixed the problem.

Comment: So the problem comes from Chrome?

Comment: yes apparently its a Chrome problem

Comment: The link that mcha points to explains it's due to Chrome not accepting/truncating pages, images or other elements with a Content-Length set to the size that is not correct.  This is a site-side code error, not really a Chrome 'error'.  Other browsers just correct/ignore the mistakes. More info [here](http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/google-chrome-blank-white-page-bug/) and [here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=74d05ae4edcf4d05&hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

Turn off Anti-Banner in Kaspersky Settings. It works for me.
Kaspersky ==> Settings ==> Protection ==> turn off Anti-Banner

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a combination of **Kaspersky** and **Chrome**.

Turn off Kaspersky's protection temporarily, and you'll see that the images stay on the page!

I've written to Kaspersky about this, and despite looking, they were unable to pin-point the problem. They only know that it started after a mid-2012 update. Also it happens on KIS, but not on PURE, etc etc.

I will send them a link to this superuser page -- maybe the other answers will help them fix this!

Comment: the question is of mid 2011 :)

Answer (score 0):

If you trust a site with this problem, you may include it in "Trusted URL" of Kaspersky Web anti-virus. This works for me.

Comment: By the way, just I saw that it issued the final version of the KES - the problem is gone!

Answer (score 0):

I began having this problem of disappearing, transparent images in Chrome on Big Sur with the new apple-silicon M1 Macbook Air. This is the apple-silicon version of Chrome. When I turn off hardware acceleration it resolves and the images appear (and it's currently highly reproducible, toggling the setting to reproduce). I'm under the impression MacOS Big Sur as of 11.1 has a lot of bugs (frequent kernel panics, etc).